# using curl with commands in go

Tags: linux, go, curl

I'm using Go with command to execute `curl` which works as expected

```
curl := exec.Command("curl", "https://services.odata.org/V3/northwind/northwind.svc/")
    out, err := curl.Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("erorr" , err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(out)
```

Now I want to use some placeholders like

```
curl -O http://quiet-waters-1228.herokuapp.com/assets/image.jpg
```

but now I need to get the url for command
e.g. if I run in bash `mytool url` I got the url value

```
`curl -O $(mytool url)`
```

The problem is that we need to execute the command in the code and I'm not sure how to pass it

```
curl := exec.Command("curl", "curl -O $(url)")
        out, err := curl.Output()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("erorr" , err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(out)
```

Comment: Why? Why invoke curl? Why not make a simple HTTP request. It seems you are adding layer over layer. Stop doing that. XY problem here?

Comment: Second that - I cannot think of any scenario where one would want to invoke curl from a Go app rather than just using the native HTTP client.

Comment: I am considering this scenario after I had to use --ntlm with curl, which seems to be impossible with go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `os` package you have slice of strings which contains all arguments passed by shell to your program.

`os.Args` 0th value, i.e., first element is going to be name of the command itself.

If your tool command is `mytool`, `os.Args[0]` contains `mytool`.

Rest are going to be the arguments, which are passed by shell.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        // If argument is not provided quit
        log.Fatalln("url not provided")
    }
    url := os.Args[1] // URL

    cmd := exec.Command("curl", "-O", url)
    cmd.Run()
}
```

You can also download multiple URLs concurrently,

```
var wg *sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    urls := os.Args[1:]

    wg = new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(len(urls))

    for _, url := range urls {
        go download(url)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}

func download(url string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    cmd := exec.Command("curl", "-O", url)
    cmd.Run()
}
```