# Golang Error - Undeclared name: xxx compiler

Tags: go, curl, visual-studio-code

I am writing a snippet of Golang to perform a curl command that was correctly written in bash script. Here is what I have so far (in VSCode):

```
url="https://<DOMAIN>/blah/blah/blah/" //<--valid url, used in bash script and it worked
cmd := exec.Command("curl", "-s --user <USERNAME> --request GET --url "+url+" --header 'Accept: application/json'")
out, err = cmd.Output()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("erorr", err)
    return false
}
fmt.Println(out)
```

All of that ends up giving me the errors "undeclared name: err (compile)" and "undeclared name: out (compile)" on the different lines where I use out and err. I saw this format used on a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53100425/using-curl-with-commands-in-go/53100510) so that's where I got this from. I can't figure out the right way to use Stdin or Stdout in this situation. Can anybody help?

Comment: Use a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) to declare the variables: `out, err := cmd.Output()`.   Note the colon.  The code in the question does not declare the variables named in the error message.

Comment: The compiler errors are pointing out invalid code and syntax. Start with [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) to get a feel for the language basics. Once you fix the syntax, the next problem is going to be the fact that you are passing all the curl arguments as a single string argument.

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler errors are due to this line, which tries to assign to two variables that (as the error says) are undeclared:

```
out, err = cmd.Output()
```

This should probably be a short variable declaration, i.e.:

```
out, err := cmd.Output()
```

However, once that's fixed, it still won't work, because you're passing all of your CLI params to curl as a single argument. It should be:

```
cmd := exec.Command("curl", "-s", "--user", "<USERNAME>", "--request", "GET", "--url", url, "--header", "Accept: application/json")
```

Though it's fairly unusual to invoke curl from a Go program; typically you'd use the HTTP client that already exists in `net/http`, so it's likely that all of this code should be replaced with use of the native client.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have missed the colon ,use `:=` instead of `=`

```
url="https://<DOMAIN>/blah/blah/blah/" //<--valid url, used in bash script and it worked
cmd := exec.Command("curl", "-s --user <USERNAME> --request GET --url "+url+" --header 'Accept: application/json'")
out, err := cmd.Output()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("erorr", err)
    return false
}
fmt.Println(out)
```